# `video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button` having `translate3d()` in iOS9's Mobile Safari. How to counter it?

Tags: css, html5-video, mobile-safari, ios9, shadow-dom

I have a `video` element on a page that has a round play button on its center. This play button is part of `video`'s shadow DOM and has style `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`. Now the problem is, if I overlay a `div` on top of this `video` (say using position absolute), A round shape appears on the top of this overlay. With the help of web inspector I found out that it's because of the `translate3d` applied to it by the user style sheet making it appear on another layer.

I wanted to counter this effect of `translate3d`. For same I added this in my page.

```
<style>
  video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
</style>
```

Inspite of this, the `translate3d` seems to take precedence. I replaced `none` with `scale(1.5,1.5)`, the circle appeared bigger and also `translate3d` was taking effect. Is there a way I can counter the useragent styles in shadow DOM?

I found this to be happening only in iOS 9 Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue with blur effect

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
     display: none;
}
```

i also had to use `position: fixed` on the video's parentNode, as mentioned by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639639/ios-9-mobile-safari-has-a-blinking-bug-with-transform-scale3d-and-translate3d)