# ios 9 mobile safari has a blinking bug with transform scale3d and translate3d

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, ios9, swiper.js

I've developed the menu of the mobile website: http://famosos.globo.com/ (click the burger icon on the bottom of the page)

Its a carousel of brands using swiper 3.0.8, when you swipe to any direction on ios 9 safari the brands keep blinking.

I found out that it's because i use transform: scale3d (also happens with normal transform: scale) while the translate3d of swiper happens.

I've tried using preserve-3d and backface-visibility tricks, but it still keeps blinking when you swipe.

I've tried to isolate the swiper and scale code on this codepen: http://codepen.io/guilhermebruzzi/pen/BoKovN but for some reason this doesn't open on ios.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
//css
.swiper-slide-active .menu-carousel-link{
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

//html
<div id="carousel" class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal">
    <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
      <li class="swiper-slide globocom-slide">
        <a href="http://globo.com/" class="menu-carousel-link">Globo.com</a>
      </li>
      <li class="swiper-slide g1-slide">
        <a href="http://g1.globo.com/" class="menu-carousel-link">G1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="swiper-slide globoesporte-slide">
        <a href="http://globoesporte.globo.com/" class="menu-carousel-link">Globoesporte</a>
      </li>
      <li class="swiper-slide famosos-slide">
        <a href="http://famosos.globo.com/" class="menu-carousel-link">Famosos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="swiper-slide techtudo-slide">
        <a href="http://techtudo.com.br/" class="menu-carousel-link">Techtudo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="swiper-slide gshow-slide">
        <a href="http://gshow.globo.com/" class="menu-carousel-link">Gshow</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

// coffeescript
class MenuWebCarousel
  constructor: ->
    @swiperContainer = $("#carousel")
    @swiperOptions = 
      resistanceRatio: 0
      spaceBetween: 10
      centeredSlides: true
      slidesPerView: 'auto'
  initSwiper: ->
    @swiperInstance = new Swiper(@swiperContainer[0], @swiperOptions)
```

Any workaround to continue to use scale and swiper on this new version of ios? Anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks! :)

Comment: the codepen full: http://codepen.io/guilhermebruzzi/full/BoKovN is now showing on iphone and it doesn't blink all the time (by swiping from right to left slowly the first brands are blinking). Can it be a gpu allocation issue?

Comment: Not an answer, but Diego's answer helped solve a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804106/angularjs-slide-transition-broken-on-safari-ios-9/32856283#32856283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem using position: fixed on the parent.

The blinking bug disappeared.

Mobile website: http://famosos.globo.com/ (click the burger icon on the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug with nested layer composition and sizing of the viewport.
Adding `overflow: hidden` in a parent layer seems to solve the problem. From a performance point of view, everything seems to be behaving the same (identical layouts, paints, compositing layers)