# angularjs slide transition broken on safari ios 9

Tags: ios, css, angularjs, mobile-safari, ios9

I have the following css classes that I use to slide my ng-view left and right at route change start.  These all work quite well on most browsers, phones, etc.  Until now...  Under ios 9  the animation is not quite working, it no longer slides left to right, but the view grows from a small size to full size while sliding, the effect is rather unpleasant.  Any help would be welcome!

CSS

`.slide-left.ng-enter,
    .slide-left.ng-leave,
    .slide-right.ng-enter,
    .slide-right.ng-leave {
        position: absolute;
        top: 58px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        background: inherit;
        -ms-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        transition:  0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
    .slide-left.ng-enter {
        z-index: 101;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .slide-left.ng-leave {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .slide-right.ng-enter {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .slide-right.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .slide-right.ng-leave {
        z-index: 101;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .slide-right.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }`

JS

`$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            //event button to move backward
            $rootScope.back = function() {
                $rootScope.slideClass = 'slide-right';
            };
            //event button item list to move forward
            $rootScope.next = function() {
                $rootScope.slideClass = 'slide-left';
            };
            $rootScope.stay = function() {
                $rootScope.slideClass = 'slide-none';
            };
        });`

MARKUP

`<div data-ng-class="slideClass" autoscroll="true" data-ng-view></div>`

---

UPDATE

---

I've arrived at a partial answer from a similar question and subsequent answer posted by Diego on [ios 9 mobile safari has a blinking bug with transform scale3d and translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639639/ios-9-mobile-safari-has-a-blinking-bug-with-transform-scale3d-and-translate3d)

I tried a similar solution as the one posted on this question.  ie. using overflow:hidden on a parent element which seems to have solved the animation problem.  I'm testing on the simulator and things seem to check out.  However, this breaks a number of other things, namely scrolling....

Quoting Diego "It seems to be a bug with nested layer composition and sizing of the viewport. Adding overflow: hidden in a parent layer seems to solve the problem. From a performance point of view, everything seems to be behaving the same (identical layouts, paints, compositing layers)"

This is going in the right direction, but not yet a correct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a thread about this [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13510)

TLDR: You need to set meta viewport's scale values to 1.0001

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0001, minimum-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Even better if you target only the IOS devices:

```
if(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream){
  document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute(
    'content', 
    'initial-scale=1.0001, minimum-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, user-scalable=no'
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that `translateX` is buggy in iOS 9 for some reason...
When I changed my transforms from `translateX(<whatever>)` to `translate3d(<whatever>, 0, 0)` things started to become sane again.

Try it.

Comment: I was using translateX. I changed to translate3d. Same result in iOS 9.

Comment: I thought you nailed it, I tried it but no luck.  translate3d still behaves the same as translateX

Comment: Oh, well... worth a shot :)